# How to export to PDF a very wide worksheet so that the PDF viewer can scroll left and right to see the whole sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to export my very wide chart on a worksheet to a PDF such that the whole chart stays on one pdf page.
To view the whole chart, the user would use the bottom scroll bar to scan left and right to view the parts of the chart that is of interest.
No matter what I have tried so far, it always breaks the chart into two pages in the PDF.
Is there a way to export the excel chart area as an image? Then the user can scan left and right with the pdf viewer scroll bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't save as PDF. Instead, use a PDF printer, like CutePDF and set a custom paper size. That will print a chart on one wide page. In this screenshot, the PDF is showing at 10% of its size. When zooming in, the chart can be explored with the horizontal scroll bars.

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea. I see what you mean.
However, it all needs to be done from VBA and each office that will use this does not necessarily have any, or the same PDF Printer.
Thanks, tho. I'll check into this idea. Is there no way to have a Custom Paper size option in the page setup?